# When I use a ScrollView with AndroidStudio, everything in my layout gets shifted down

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tools:context=".view.characterlist.HaruActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/harubackgound"
    >

...


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is a picture of the screen without ScrollView :
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/473468257626488852/722442283181539409/unknown.png

And here with :
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/473468257626488852/722441710067777617/unknown.png

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".view.characterlist.HaruActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/harubackgound"
    >


   ...

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Could someone help me ? Ty

Comment: Share full contents of the new xml layout with `ScrollView`. To debug this issue it is not enough to see only two top elements.

Comment: What happens if you change all `wrap_content`s with `match_parent`?

Comment: It doesn't change anything with the problem to change into `match_parent`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/19s08DNw here is full code

Answer (score -1):

try setting the image as a background, so you would add:

```
android:background = "@drawable/...
```

in the parent relative layout.

I believe that all the textviews are going down because the image is currently in an imageview, and if you want to overlay textview over the image, then you need to set image as the background.